I want to upload large video files to firebase storage from my flutter app
here's how the uploading happens the code has flutterflow functionality in it as well since it was migrated from it and I am gradually shifting away from its functionality I checked the firebase storage rules as well
onPressed: () async {
  final selectedMedia = await selectMedia(
    isVideo: true,
    mediaSource: MediaSource.videoGallery,
    multiImage: false,
  );
  if (selectedMedia != null && selectedMedia.every((m) =>
    validateFileFormat(
    m.storagePath, context))) {
      setState(() => _model.isDataUploading1 = true);
      var selectedUploadedFiles = <FFUploadedFile>[];

      var downloadUrls = <String>[];
      try {
      showUploadMessage(
      context,
      'Uploading file...',
      showLoading: true,
      );
      selectedUploadedFiles = selectedMedia
      .map((m) => FFUploadedFile(
      name: m.storagePath
      .split('/')
      .last,
      bytes: m.bytes,
      height: m.dimensions?.height,
      width: m.dimensions?.width,
      blurHash: m.blurHash,
      ))
      .toList();

      downloadUrls = (await Future.wait(
      selectedMedia.map(
      (m) async => await uploadData(
      m.storagePath, m.bytes),
      ),
    ))
    .where((u) => u != null)
    .map((u) => u!)
    .toList();
    } finally { ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
    _model.isDataUploading1 = false;
    }
    if (selectedUploadedFiles.length == selectedMedia.length &&     downloadUrls.length == selectedMedia.length) {
       setState(() {_model.uploadedLocalFile1 = selectedUploadedFiles.first;
    _model.uploadedFileUrl1 = downloadUrls.first;
    });
    showUploadMessage(context, 'Success!');
    } else {
      setState(() {});
      showUploadMessage(context, 'Failed to upload data');
        return;
    }
  }
},

here's the storage rules
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }

    // Allow public read access to PDF files
    match /pdfs/{pdfFile} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null && 
                   pdfFile.matches('.*\\.pdf');
    }
    
    // Maintain existing user-specific rules
    match /users/{userId}/{allPaths=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}


I tried testing with a 700mb video file and I was met with a stuck loading for a while with then again I was able to select video for upload I guess the task terminated and I can also provide some debugging logs

loosening up your firebase storage rules will do the trick

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
